# simple attribute parsing with encoded double-quotes

Tags: java, regex

I'm parsing some text in Java with a Regex

I have strings that look like this:  myAttribute="some text", and am parsing them like this

```
Pattern attributePattern = Pattern.compile("[a-z0-9]*=\"[^\"]*\"");
```

However, I realise people may want to use double-quotes in their attribute values.

e.g. myAttribute="some text with a double quote \" here"

How do I adjust my regex to handle this

Here is my code that parses the attributes

```
private HashMap<String, String> findAttributes(String macroAttributes) {
    Matcher matcher = attributePattern.matcher(macroAttributes);
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String attribute = macroAttributes.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end());
        int equalsIndex = attribute.indexOf("=");
        String attrName = attribute.substring(0, equalsIndex);
        String attrValue = attribute.substring(equalsIndex+2, attribute.length()-1);
        map.put(attrName, attrValue);
    }
    return map;
}

findAttributes("my=\"some text with a double quote \\\" here\"");
```

Should return a map of size 1
The Value should be some text with a double quote \" here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an alternation and a positive lookbehind assertion for that

```
Pattern attributePattern = Pattern.compile("[a-z0-9]*=\"(?:[^\"]*|(?<=\\\\)\")*\"");
```

`(?:[^\"]*|(?<=\\\\)\")*` is an alternation, matching either `[^\"]*` or `(?<=\\\\)\"`

`(?<=\\\\)\"` is matching a ", but only if it is preceded by a backlash.

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly!  I see I have to escape normal slashes now, but that is fine.  Many tx

Answer (score 1):

You could use negative look behind to see if there's a backslash before the quote, but that fails if the backslashes themselves can be escaped too:

```
myAttribute="some text with a trailing backslash \\"
```

If that is possible, try something like this:

```
Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]+=\"([^\"\\\\]|\\\\[\"\\\\])*\"")
```

A quick explanation:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+     # the key
=                # a literal '='
\"               # a literal '"'
(                # start group
  [^\"\\\\]      #   any char except '\' and '"'
  |              #   OR
  \\\\[\"\\\\]   # either '\\' or '\"'
)*               # end group and repeat zero or more times
\"               # a literal '"'
```

A quick demo:

```
public class Main {

    private static HashMap<String, String> findAttributes(Pattern p, String macroAttributes) {
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(macroAttributes);
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        while (matcher.find()) {
            map.put(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2));
        }
        return map;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String text = "my=\"some text with a double quote \\\" here\"";
        System.out.println(findAttributes(Pattern.compile("([a-z0-9]+)=\"((?:[^\"\\\\]|\\\\[\"\\\\])*)\""), text));
        System.out.println(findAttributes(Pattern.compile("([a-z0-9]*)=\"((?:[^\"]*|(?<=\\\\)\")*)\""), text));
    }
}
```

will print:

```
{my=some text with a double quote \" here}
{my=some text with a double quote \}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tested that pattern but it didn't seem to work.  I've put some sample code into the question to show what I am currently doing.  With your pattern it still seems to end at the \".  Stema seems to have suggested one that works, so I've marked his as correct.  (If you correct your's I'll gladly give you an upvote for your time and effort)

Comment: @BruceLowe, I just tested it too, and it works like a charm. Checkout the demo I posted.

Comment: @BruceLowe, and note that you can use [match-groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to extract the keys and values (you don't need to do any `substring` yourself).

Comment: Thanks Bart for the tips and effort!